# Why do browsers not protect against scripts coming with images?

Tags: malware, web-browser, buffer-overflow

I understand that this is how it goes:

```
Malformed Image --> Buffer Overrun --> Stack Over Flow --> Execute Malware Pushed On Stack
```

And though I don't a huge amount about this, I know that I have had many of these malicious scripts come with images before that have done nasty things within my browser hiding in my cache, but why does do most browsers not protect against this? Is this something exploited through vulnerabilities (if so, there seem to be far too many of them as I've had far too many of these malicious scripts)? Or why is it so difficult to have protection against this?

I just understood from [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=29378727#29378727) that browsers don't protect against these things and I want to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did answer your own question already:

> Is this something exploited through vulnerabilities   ...   Buffer
>   Overrun

Buffer overflows are not intended behaviour, but indeed exploitable vulnerabilities. Browsers vendors *will* fix B.O. when they find it => they do protect from it. The problem is, as with all vulnerabilities, someone has to recognize that there is an error in the code first.

What your chat log says, that browsers don't use some preventive additional security features which could help against an existing error being exploited (eg. because these methods have downsides too). But they will fix the errors itself.

> as I've had far too many of these malicious scripts

That could have thousands of reasons, other than images with scripts. Given that you seem to think that "buffer overrun" is always the same as "stack overflow", you probably didn't recognize some of the reasons.

Comment: So if I get a malicious script and I suspect that it is due to an unpatched vulnerability being exploited is there any way I can gather more information in order to report it to the security team of the browser?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda As "normal" user, not really. If you suspect a certain website, sending them a link so that can get first-hand data is probably the most effective (and most easy). Add infos like which browser and operating system you use, where you clicked on this site etc. (and of course, what happened that you think it is malicious).